# SQL Server sys.credentials Permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2014, credentials

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ms189745.aspx) the user should have either `VIEW ANY DEFINITION` or `ALTER ANY CREDENTIAL` to view the credentials. The issue is when I grant this permission, the user can see all the credentials. Is there a way to limit the user can view only one credential in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Have you looked at module signing? That is, create a stored procedure and then use `create signature` to sign it (and grant permissions based on the certificate that signed it).

Answer (score 0):

You create a new view object that looks at the `sys.credentials` table based on the current user login, e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.GetAllowedCredentials
AS
SELECT  c.credential_id,
        c.name,
        c.credential_identity,
        c.create_date,
        c.modify_date,
        c.target_type,
        c.target_id
FROM    sys.credentials AS c
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS sp ON sp.credential_id = c.credential_id
WHERE   sp.name = ORIGINAL_LOGIN();
```

You can apply permissions to this view as required.